Infering complex literal type
I want to infer literals when using function.
Desired behaviour:
When I'm using this function the option's invalidate should offer awaited return type of the method provided from api as parameter, so I don't have to manually type it.
Current behaviour:
It offers return types of all methods from api.
Function code:
type TestMap<TApi extends ApiGeneric<TApi>, TOptions extends Record<keyof TOptions, {
  method: keyof TApi;
  key: (...args: any) => any;
  argumentMapper?: ApiFunction<any>;
  invalidate?: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<TApi[keyof TApi]>>) => QueryKey[];
  useSignal?: boolean;
}>, TOptionsKey extends keyof TOptions, TApiKey extends keyof TApi> = {
  [Key in TOptionsKey]: {
    method: TOptions[Key]['method']
    key: TOptions[Key]['key'];
    argumentMapper?: ApiFunction<any>;
    useSignal?: boolean;
    onSuccess?: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<TApi[TOptions[Key]['method']]>>, variables: TOptions[Key]['argumentMapper'] extends (...args: any) => any ? Parameters<TOptions[Key]['argumentMapper']> : Parameters<TApi[keyof TApi]>, ctx: unknown) => void;
    invalidate?: (data: TApiKey extends TApi[TOptions[Key]['method']] ? Awaited<ReturnType<TApi[TApiKey]>> : Awaited<ReturnType<TApi[TOptions[Key]['method']]>>) => QueryKey[];
  }
}

export function mutationFactory<
  TOptionsKey extends keyof TOptions,
  TApi extends ApiGeneric<TApi>,
  TOptions extends {
    [Key in TOptionsKey]: {
      method: keyof TApi;
      key: (...args: Parameters<TOptions[Key]['key']>) => any;
      argumentMapper?: ApiFunction<any> | undefined;
      invalidate: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<TApi[TOptions[Key]['method']]>>) => QueryKey[],
      useSignal?: boolean | undefined;
    }
  },
  TApiKey extends TOptions[TOptionsKey]['method'],
  >(api: TApi, baseName: string, options: TestMap<TApi, TOptions, TOptionsKey, TOptions[TOptionsKey]['method']>){
...logic
}

Usage:
const productMutations = mutationFactory(productsApi, 'product', {
  update: {
    method: 'updateProductVersion',
    key: mutationKeys.update,
    invalidate: (data) => [ productQueryKeysFinal.retrieveById({ productId: data.id }), productQueryKeysFinal.retrieveHistoryById({ productId: data.id }) ],
  }
});

I tried using a lot of approaches and nothing helped.
Thank you for all helps and sorry for the mess I have in this code right now, it's "try/fail" I will make it better later.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research .  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
